# Working with arrays in puppet

Tags: puppet

I have a variable `$IP = [ "91" , "92" ]`and `$IPPriveeInstance = "10.248.33.$IP"`.

You guessed it, I want to use this variable 2 times,but when I print `IPPriveeInstance`, I got the output as 10.248.33.9192.

Comment: This should be asked on http://stackoverflow.com. I have put in a request for it to be transferred there.

Comment: @Caleb: Puppet is a programming language, but it's a very specific very limited programming language **for system administration**.  It's totally on topic here, even if it is *also* on-topic on StackOverflow.

Comment: What are you expecting to print?  If you set the `IPPriveeInstance` variable to one address or the other, you'll only have... one address.  Give us more information on what you're trying to accomplish (populating a config file?  passing those in to a module?), and we'll be able to help.

Comment: Hi im trying to test if files (named with IPPriveeInstance  exist in client) so the need of an array as you see.Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Puppet does not iterate array items. The example below demonstrates with inline_template, but you should use a custom function to perform this task.

```
$ip      = ['91', '92']
$address = '10.248.33.'
$array   = inline_template("<%= ip.collect{|x| address+x.to_s} %>")
```

You can also write this via the Ruby DSL: http://projects.puppetlabs.com/projects/1/wiki/Ruby_Dsl

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to reference the full array at once when you want the individual parts of the arrays separately. Try this:

```
$IPPriveeInstance = "10.248.33.$IP[0]"
$IPPriveeInstance = "10.248.33.$IP[1]"
```

The first index in an array is always zero.

Comment: Sorry,but that doesn't seem to be working.Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

[Puppet 7 supports iterations](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/7/lang_iteration.html) (also earlier version 5, 6 for sure):

```
$ip = ['91', '92']

$ip.each |String $value| {
  $private = "10.248.33.$value"
  notice("IP: $private")
}
```

the output would be:

```
$ puppet apply test.pp 
Notice: Scope(Class[main]): IP: 10.248.33.91
Notice: Scope(Class[main]): IP: 10.248.33.92
```